# Specify kernel include header path when "cross"-build from VERY OLD kernel

Tags: build, kernel

yes, I know, it's very "late", but: I want to compile a 3.2 kernel (longterm) on an existing 2.4 system. Yes, I need to compile it there, sorry.

The problem: The system's include/header files are very old. 2.4 kernel's ones.

When building the new kernel it complains about undefined symbols etc.

The problem is that it uses system's header files instead of it's own ones.

QUESTION: How can I specify that the build process uses it's own header files instead of the system's ones?

THANK YOU :-)

UPDATE (as requested in comment)

I am using version 3.2.94 (latest 3.x):

```
make defconfig
make
```

I am getting these errors

```
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c: In function `sym_type':
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:145: `STT_COMMON' undeclared (first use in this function)
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:145: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:145: for each function it appears in.)
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:145: nonconstant array index in initializer
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:145: (near initialization for `type_name')
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:146: `STT_TLS' undeclared (first use in this function)
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:146: nonconstant array index in initializer
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:146: (near initialization for `type_name')
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c: In function `sym_visibility':
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:176: `STV_DEFAULT' undeclared (first use in this function)
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:176: nonconstant array index in initializer
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:176: (near initialization for `visibility_name')
(...)
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c: In function `collect_reloc':
arch/x86/tools/relocs.c:653: `R_386_16' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:118: arch/x86/tools/relocs] Error 1
make: *** [/root/linux-3.2.94/arch/x86/Makefile:121: archscripts] Error 2
```

I searched for the contants like STT_COMMON. They are just in the include headers the kernel source contains, but NOT my system one.

Comment: `How can I specify that the build process uses it's own header files instead of the system's ones?` - Such behavior should be **by default**. Update your question with **exact commands** you use and **exact error** you get.

Comment: I made an update. Thank you @Tsyvarev

Comment: Well, the question become clear. With operation `CC <...>` *kernel* object is compiled, and kernel's headers are used. But `HOSTCC <...>` operation compiles *user-space* object, so it should be **suitable** for your compiler and your libraries. For that reason, with `HOSTCC` operation system headers are used, not the ones intended for the kernel. BTW, in 3.2. version the header, contained *STT_COMMON* symbol, is `/include/linux/elf.h` (kernel-specific). But with modern 4.+ kernels the header is `/include/uapi/linux/elf.h`, that it is *could* be used for user things.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to "switch" from HOSTCC to CC?